# Who determines a hard fork

Tags: blockchain-fork, nodes

I'm trying to really get a deep understanding of the roles miners and nodes play in enforcing the Bitcoin rules.

If a hard fork is presented, who determines if the fork is accepted, nodes or miners? I was under the assumption that it would be nodes since nodes verify the data. A friend was telling me that miners also get to determine what rules are enforced.

Can someone explain to me in plain speak the roles the two of them play in enforcing rules?

Additionally how does one technically propose a Hard fork, does an individual literally change the code on their Bitcoin Core pacakge and try to have it accepted by the network?

Thanks!

Jon